# Rails query to substitute field and query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

could someone please help me to write a query to substitute hyphens in rails DB field with space?
For eg:
If I have a field called 'name' in a table User having a value 'asdc-sd bc', and want to remove special characters like '-' and replace it with space to match with a given name 'asdc sd bc'.

I tried using lower to convert the name to lowercase but am not able to find out how to substitute the hyphens with space. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL [REPLACE](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-string-functions/sql-replace/) function to replace `-` with spaces(' ').
For example, if you are querying on `name` column of `User` model, you can write your query like below:

```
query_str = 'asdc sd bc'
User.where("REPLACE(name, '-', ' ') = ?", query_str)
```